# I want to go back to specific page of a tabViewController from different viewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have implemented a tabViewController with some pages. one of those page is a tableview controller. after clicking on tableview item i am opening another viewController. Now i want to go back to that specific page. the selectedIndex of that tab Page is 1.
How can i do this?

Thanks for your help

[store board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jMnA.png)

Comment: Slightly off topic: Don't switch tabs for a user. It violates the principle of a tab bar controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let tabBar: UITabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController

tabBar.selectedIndex = 1
```

Comment: i cant access this code from that viewController. I have attached the story board image. may be this can help to get some idea about my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are outside from tabBar Controller.

```
self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
```

If you are already in tabBar Controller and move to another tabBar Controller. Go to the ViewDid of TabBar method and paste the code.

```
     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.selectedIndex = 1
    }
```

Comment: I am outside from tabBar Controller. But that code is not working. 
I am using segue to open single viewController when any list item has been clicked. Is this the cause of this problem?

Comment: let tabBar: UITabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController            tabBar.selectedIndex = 1

Comment: add this line also

Comment: This error is showing while adding this code: "Value of type 'CardDetailsViewController' has no member 'window'"

Comment: go to the tabBar class. in viewdid load add self.selectedIndex = 1

Comment: @forhadhossain now when you get back. you see the specific tabar is open . i also update the answer as welll

Comment: But if i do so, that tab will open every time loads the app. I have to something from the single viewController (not the tab or tabcontroller)

Comment: then you make separate viewcontroller. its best approach.

Comment: I have solved the problem using segue and prepare for segue method. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @forhadhossain Thats Great Man

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user to be able to go back to tableViewController after clicking on a cell you should use a navigationController instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are using UITabBarController as rootViewController then can do this:

```
if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate{
        if let rootTabBarController = appDelegate.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController{
            rootTabBarController.selectedIndex = 1
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have solved the problem using segue and prepare for segue method. Thanks anyway.